# AWS Lambda links not working with RDS Postgres

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, endpoint

I'm using Ruby on Jets (Rack based framework for AWS Lambda) for an AWS Lambda and using a Postgres RDS DB. All of my functions are now implemented but when I test or click and API endpoint through API Gateway, it times out and with a test, I get an error that is not giving me much information:

[image: image of Lambda error]

Not sure if it's a VPC issue. I only have one VPC that was setup when I created the RDS DB:

[image: VPC for Lambda]

and

[image: VPC for RDS]

I know the RDS DB is working because I'm able to access in local development.

Any ideas what might be happening here? I'm new to AWS configuration.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the Lambda to be run in your VPC as well?

Comment: Use logging statements to debug it.

Comment: Is the database publicly reachable or not? Ideally it's not, in which case the Lambda should be run in the VPC hosting the database (typically in a private subnet) and with a security group that the DB allows inbound access from.

Comment: The DB is publicly available but that was set up out of ignorance. The db is in a VPC. I guess I need to configure the security group and match the Lambda functions to that?

Comment: If the rds is in a private subnet then lambda must also run in same vpc and a private subnet.

Comment: I just configured it that way (I think) and still no luck.

Comment: Seems likely that you have some kind of connection taking too long (wild guess is that its postgres) and your process does not have time to timeout and return a useful message. Instead, its 30 seconds expires and amazon kills your lambda and you get nothing.

Configure your postgres client (and any other tcp clients) with shorter timeouts, or allocate a couple of minutes to your lambda and I bet you'll see the real error.

Comment: Very interesting. By extending the Lambda function timeout to 59 seconds and the test passes. When I click the link in API Gateway, it still times out. A separate issue perhaps is the static s3 react deployment link getting a 403. That's probably a React Router issue.